# List of a list alternative solution for data structure C#

Tags: c#, list

I was wondering if there is a better way to design a similar data structure.

`object --> list of objects --> list of lists`

Example of the code is below:

```
class Customer
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}

class Customers
{
    public List<Customer> {get; set}
}

class MultipleLists_Customers
{
    public List<Customers> {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Hard to judge a design without knowing the requirements. What is the problem that is being solved by this data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design is about representing a problem domain, so your design might be good or bad depending what the problem is....  renaming some things, it might be quite valid for something like

```
class Customer
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public string LastName {get; set;}
}

class Vendor
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public List<Customer> Customers {get;set}
}

class Organization
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public List<Vendor> Vendors {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Keith notes, renaming is a good start.

If all you really want is an object representing a list of lists of objects, you can achieve it without creating a new data structure by simply nesting generics:

```
public List<List<Customer>> CustomerLists;
```

That said, it seems you're trying to model an ordering system. Something like this does the trick:

```
class Customer
{
    public Customer(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
}

class Vendor
{
    public Vendor(string name, IEnumerable<Product> products)
    {
        Name = name;
        Products = new HashSet<Product>(products);
    }

    public bool HasStock(Product product, double quantity)
    {
        // determine if product is currently in stock...
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public HashSet<Product> Products { get; }
}

class Product
{
    // ... common product data.
}

class Order
{
    public Order(
        DateTime createDate, Customer customer, 
        Vendor vendor, Product product, double quantity)
    {
        CreateDate = createDate;
        Customer = customer;
        Vendor = vendor;
        Product = product;
        Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; }
    public Customer Customer { get; }
    public Vendor Vendor { get; }
    public Product Product { get; }
    public double Quantity { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way is this:

```
class Customer
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}

class MultipleLists_Customers
{
    public List<Customer> Customers {get; set;}
}
```